# how to debug web request in python

Tags: python, debugging

I've been using pdb to debug through terminal while developing a python cli app.

I'm having a hard time finding examples that will show me how to use pdb in the context of a web request (using apache or some other web server). In PHP passing XDEBUG_SESSION_START as part of the request will drop me into a debug session. I'm wondering how I can accomplish the same thing with pdb.

Comment: What kind of web framework are you using? PDB just needs a terminal, many web frameworks can be run in a single-thread setup attached to a terminal so you can use PDB.

Comment: Is your question about pdb usage in general? If you have a plain CLI app, I don't see any problem using pdb. For web request debugging in general, I'd recommend [Fiddler 2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: What kind of web framework are you using? If you are using Django, it has build-in debug settings. After you enable, it can display whole stack traces, http related information for your error or exception.